# Live JSON requests from a datalogger

Tags: jquery, json, url

For our energy dashboard i've made a widget with 2 gauges with active power values of our solar inverters. We use a datalogger which is able to send a JSON string with the desired parameters via a http request. In this script you see a var SolarB (this is the actual JSON string after an http request as example). This is to check if the values are coded correctly and presented in the gauges.
The SolarA is the live json request. This should be the final code for both SolarA and B in order to have a live connection. I've tried several ways to get this working, searched the internet and this forum for answers but without succes. I thought it was a simple problem but it's giving me headaches... Any help is appreciated.

Tia

Peter

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Real time Data aquisition Solar inverters</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style>
  body {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #g1, #g2 {
    width:250px; height:180px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em;
  }

  p {
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    margin: 2em auto;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>

<script src="resources/js/raphael.2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/justgage.1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>

{
 var SolarA = ""
    $.getJSON("//192.168.16.201/rest/devices/2912280908/values/variables/596355681/instant", function(data)
    { SolarA = data;
  });

 var SolarB = [{ "time": 1396898708, "value": 11.748850e+00, "unit": "kW" }, ];
 var g1, g2;

  window.onload = function(){
    var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "g1", 
      value: document.getElementById.innerHTML=SolarA[0].value, 
      min: 0,
      max: 30000,
      title: "Production A",
      label: document.getElementById.innerHTML=SolarA[0].unit
    });

    var g2 = new JustGage({
      id: "g2", 
      value: document.getElementById.innerHTML=SolarB[0].value, 
      min: 0,
      max: 13800,
      title: "Production B",
      label: document.getElementById.innerHTML=SolarB[0].unit

    });

  };

 };

</script>

</head>
<body>    
<div id="g1"></div>
<div id="g2"></div>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you actually wrote what is the problem with the above code, since there are several things that might have one wrong(SolarB gauge works? An error is thrown? Etc).

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is wrong is that you are creating the gauges before the data is available.

Probably your data is returned after the gauges are created, so the order of events is as follows:

1. `$.getJSON("//192.168.16.201 ...` is called,
2. your page has finished loading, `onload` function is executed,
3. `var g1 = new JustGage({ ...` and `var g2 = new JustGage({ ...` are created
4. your device returns the data, `function(data){ SolarA = data; }` is called

Note that in JS, callbacks won't block the executin of your script, but rather will be executed sometime in the future, so you can't rely on them being executed in commands after `$.getJSON`.

If that is the case, solution to your problem would be to move the gauge creation into the callback function so:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $.getJSON("//192.168.16.201/rest/devices/2912280908/values/variables/596355681/instant",
      function(data) { 
        new JustGage({
          id: "g1", 
          value: document.getElementById.innerHTML = data[0].value, 
          min: 0,
          max: 30000,
          title: "Production A",
          label: document.getElementById.innerHTML = data[0].unit
        });
      }
    );
  });
</script>
```

Note that the problem also might be that when you view your website from a computer that is not in `192.168.16.*` then the data is simply unreachable - JavaScript works on clients side. In that case you would need to write a client - server webapp.

It's also possible that you are trying to perform a [cross site HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: All the data logged, requested and is shown in the 192.168 etc. network. I was indeed not clear about what the problem was. By simulating these gauges with the JSON string I tested the widget. After that I tried the getJSON live connection without success.
Your answer is very clear and I will try your suggestion and let you know if this works. Thanks!